# Created a new remote and Github though empty, says everything-up-to-date

Tags: git, github, repository

I did :

```
git add remote git@github.com:username/name_of_github_repo.git
git push -u github master
```

It returns :

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from github.
Everything up-to-date
```

I check the website, and nothing has been uploaded no branches have been added. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I added and removed files. Commmited and pushed them. It returned this :

```
Mac-Users-MacBook-Pro:item macuser$ git push -u org master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 233 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:username/Project.git
   114aa31..adf1ece  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from org.
```

Checked the site, still nothing.

Then I tried :

```
git push -all
```

That returned :

```
everything-up-to-date
```

This project has already been committed to Heroku and this is a new remote that I am adding. Possibly that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how or why but this ended up doing it :

```
git push -u org master:org
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your master branch there and not other branches?  If so, try `git push --all` to push all the branches.

Comment: Nope. Tried that, and updated some of my findings above. Thanks~

Comment: This may be obvious, but did you try refreshing the page? Are you sure you are looking at the correct repo?

Comment: Is your first command correct?  You have `git add remote...` which is not the same as `git remote add...`?